# SQL SERVER - OPENROWSET with filepath parameter

Tags: sql-server, openrowset, xml-import

I have this SQL script tht work properly:

```
INSERT INTO #XMLwithOpenXML(XMLData, LoadedDateTime)
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\temp\test.wordpress.2017-05-22.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;


SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM #XMLwithOpenXML
```

Now I need to pass the xml file path with a variable.

How do I have to change the script?

Thanks to support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL:

```
create table #XMLwithOpenXML(XMLData xml, LoadedDateTime DateTime)

declare @xml xml
declare @filename nvarchar(100)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set  @filename ='F:\a.xml'
set  @sql = 'INSERT INTO #XMLwithOpenXML(XMLData, LoadedDateTime) '
set  @sql = @sql +' SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() '
set  @sql = @sql +' FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + @filename +''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;'

EXEC (@Sql)

SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM #XMLwithOpenXML

SELECT @XML

drop table #XMLwithOpenXML
```